# File location issue in IOS voice recording using cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

I was developed ios hybrid app and i using cordova for recording and uploading the audio files and it works fine. I found the file location like **/private/var/mobile/Media/Recordings/**. but i cant view the recorded audio file location in ios mobile.
During uploading i want to get the file from file location. Please help me to find out